# How to find out what application slows down the system (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, performance

Sometimes (~once-twice a day) I experience slowdowns (up to freezing for 5-10 seconds) and I don't know their cause. I tried looking into Process Explorer, but it shows only current rates and history columns are of no help either.

So, what is the right way to find the answer to the question "what have just slowed down the system"?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: This may have already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process

Comment: Remember, you can hover over the history graphs to see what application used the most of that resource at the given time.

Comment: @Dez, Windows 7

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, doesn't help - the graphs are showing that the load was minimal.

Comment: @Fixpoint Please see if [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/202254/how-do-i-get-to-the-root-cause-of-high-deferred-procedure-calls) might relate to you issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). This should help in showing which program is using up your system resources.

Or try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), which lists all the processes that are running. You should be able to determine what program is slowing down your system with both of these tools.

Comment: I'm already using Process Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

If Process Explorer isn't enough, you might want to look into [xperf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh162945%28v=win.10%29).

Sadly, I don't have the time right now to go into usage details, but maybe [this video](https://web.archive.org/web/20160225123526/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/03/22/using-xperf-to-root-cause-cpu-consumption.aspx) and [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Profiling_with_Xperf) will get you started in the meantime.